# How to call a function inside Firebase email login Task in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, email, firebase-authentication, task

On My unity app, inside login using email and password, I am using firebase login. My problem is when I try to call a function or execute a group code inside the task nothing happen. Not even an error. How to call a function inside this.

```
public void signin()
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWith(task => {
         if (task.IsCanceled) 
         {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
         if (task.IsFaulted)
         {
        Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
        return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;

        //========Checking Email Verified Or Not======

        if(auth.CurrentUser.IsEmailVerified== true)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

         //=================Here is the Problem this is not calling==========
           MyFunction();
         //==============================================
        }
        else
        {
        print("Email Not Verified");
        auth.SignOut(); 
        }
        //===========
       
        });     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the most common issue with these kind of things is that most of the Unity API can only be used on the main thread.

The [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) is not guaranteed to be executed in the main thread but might happen in any async background thread/task

Therefore Firebase provides an extension method [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) you should use instead, which makes sure the inner codeblock is executed on the Unity main thread.

So simply replace

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWith(task => {
```

with

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
```

make sure you have `using Firebase.Extensions` at the top of your file